# Labels not displaying - why? - Using wxPython-Phoenix

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to create a simple graphical interface with **wxPython-Phoenix** but the widgets are not displaying and I'm not sure why.

I have choose to use **wx.FlexGridSizer()** as the sizer to handle the widgets positioning.

Attached is my code:

```
class App_Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,title=""):

    #Containers
    main_Frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,title)
    main_Panel = wx.Panel(self)

    #-----------Controls------------

    #Deal Name
    Deal_Name_Lbl = wx.StaticText(main_Panel,-1,"Deal Name:",style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    Deal_Name_Txt = wx.TextCtrl(main_Panel,-1,"Deal Name")

    #Num Copies
    Num_Copies_lbl = wx.StaticText(main_Panel,-1,"Number of Copies:",style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    Num_Copies_Txt = wx.TextCtrl(main_Panel,-1,"Num Copies")



    #--------------Sizer--------------
    flex_grid_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2,vgap=6,hgap=6)
    flex_grid_sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

    #Adding objs to sizer
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(Deal_Name_Lbl,0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(Deal_Name_Txt,0,wx.EXPAND)

    flex_grid_sizer.Add(Num_Copies_lbl,0,wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(Num_Copies_Txt,0,wx.EXPAND)

    #Set and fit sizer
    self.SetSizer(flex_grid_sizer)
    self.Fit()

class App_(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        Main_Frame = App_Frame("Paper")
        Main_Frame.Show()
        return True

#--------------------- MAIN FUNCTION ----------------------
def Main():
    Main_Window = App_()

    Main_Window.MainLoop()

#--- Call of Main----
Main()
```

... and the output I get is the following:

[image]

Any type of guidance would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't add the panel to the **Main** window

```
...
#Set and fit sizer
main_Panel.SetSizer(flex_grid_sizer)
box = wx.BoxLayout()
box.add(main_Panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
self.setSizer(box)
self.Fit()
```